# How can I cluster the following data set to find out the time when ozone and pm level are high in different stations using R?

Tags: r, clustering, data-mining, spatio-temporal

My data set contains around 630,000 rows and the data set looks like this:

date                   site     code  latitude longitude rollingo3 rollingpm2.5

1 2015-01-01 17:00:00 Aberdeen ABD       57.2     -2.09      58.5         5.96
2 2015-01-01 18:00:00 Aberdeen ABD       57.2     -2.09      57.6         5.92
3 2015-01-01 19:00:00 Aberdeen ABD       57.2     -2.09      57.5         5.88
4 2015-01-01 20:00:00 Aberdeen ABD       57.2     -2.09      55.4         5.91
5 2015-01-01 21:00:00 Aberdeen ABD       57.2     -2.09      55.4         5.81
6 2015-01-01 22:00:00 Aberdeen ABD       57.2     -2.09      57.9         5.75

it contains hourly 8 hour rolling mean of ozone and pm2.5 from different monitoring stations from 2015 to 2016. I wish to cluster the times when the pollution level is high. How can I achieve that in R? 
I am trying dbscan and kmeans algorithm on the columns rollingo3 and rolling pm2.5 and an hour coloumn not listed here containing the time of the day. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just visualize your data e.g. like [this](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/heatmap/) with a facet on site (small multiples), then look at the ozone levels.

Regarding the how, have a look at R's recent [DataExplorer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataExplorer/index.html) or the [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) packages. IMO no clustering is needed here, for you already know what you are looking for.

Comment: can you suggest any algorithm other than k-means that can find interesting patterns from the data set concerning the time and level of pollution?

Comment: I do not think that clustering only will help you here. In this precise case, visual exploration may yield equivalent if not even better results, plus if you insist on clustering, any insights gained from the former will still be useful. Above all, take your time to define the problem at hand and bring in some domain knowledge.